# Blob data Retrieving in java shows non readable format

Tags: java

I have a table in which one column has xml data, so the column type is blob. When I try to retrieve using java by jdbc. I can extract but when I print it show the content as non-readable format. What should I do for getting the proper xml from table?

```
try {
            // Executing the select statement
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("column_name");
            // blob is in binary stream
            InputStream inStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
            StringBuffer payLoad = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null ){
            payLoad.append(line);
            }

inStream.close();
```

the above code im using for retrieving the blob data db. Anything i need to correct here ?

Comment: How are you trying to display the data?

Comment: What is the character set in the xml?

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller im just converting the stringbuffer payload to string and displaying

Comment: @JonathanHenson UTF-8 is characterset

Comment: Displaying _how_? `System.out.println`? A `JTextPane`? Are you possibly encountering a component that is trying to interpret the tags?

Comment: I'm displaying using sop only.